# Example of linearly dependent vectors in a module that are not multiples

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that if S = {$ s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$} is a linearly dependent set of vectors in a vector space iff one of the vectors can be written in terms of the others. In a module, however, my text says that this is not necessarily the case. I am trying to think of an example of a module in which a set of vectors are lin. dep. but none can be written in terms of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then any two rational numbers are linearly dependent, but they need not be integer multiples of each other. It follows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not free as well.